# Why is getOnBackPressedDispatcher() method unresolved until 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui' is added as a dependency?

Tags: android-navigation, android-jetifier

I'm trying to customize `onBackPress` behaviour of JetPack Navigation. Although [I found the solution](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back#java) I'm just curious what's going behind the scenes in the following scenario:

Initial state of my activity is

```
MyActivity extends androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(...);  // <--- Method is unresolved
    }
}
```

How come that after I add the following dependency to build.gradle the `getOnBackPressedDispatcher()` method is being resolved:

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
```

What's going behind the scenes?

- Does it have something with the Jetifier?
- Does it alter the classes based on declared dependencies or something similar?
- Or is it a Kotlin stuff (extension or something)?

Comment: If you mean the solution to resolve the dependency problem, then it is already presented in the question itself (`getOnBackPressedDispatcher()` is being resolved after adding `navigation-fragment` and `navigation-ui` dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

So it's a Kotlin extension. Google's Bard provided the answer (what a world :)):

**Extension Method**: `getOnBackPressedDispatcher()` is not a member of `AppCompatActivity` itself. It's an extension method provided by the Navigation libraries.

Answer (score -1):

> implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

Implement this dependency to its latest version, this will fix the problem.